# Opening Slack logs my user out of ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, logout, desktop-apps, slack

As soon as I start slack app(snap) I get logged out of my user in Ubuntu 18.04.

I will provide more info if I can check things before it logs me out. Can you please suggest how I check for some logs and also how to fix this issue.

Here is a `dmesg` output after logging back in -> https://pastebin.com/uzqXUe1C

Comment: One log you can check after logging in again is running `dmesg` in Terminal.

Comment: same here. no solution yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to me as well when installing from the snap repository.

I uninstalled the snap, removed the `~/.config/Slack` folder and then reinstalled from deb file. I downloaded it from here: https://slack.com/downloads/linux

The app worked on first try and after reboot it kept working. Hope it helps.

Comment: worked for me, seems that the problem is with slack snap.

Comment: I also had do run `sudo apt remove slack`, otherwise the installation crashed.